# Is it possible to check if the mouse pointer is on the certain class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it function in jQuery? Pseudo code:

```
$('.smth').bind('mouseout', function(){
    if($('.certain_class').magic_function()) {
      $('.fading_object_class').fadeOut("fast");
    }
});
```

If mouse pointer is not on the class `certain_class`, it would fade.

P.S. It's for my tooltip plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some pseudo-code.  But the main point here is that you can use [hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) if the element that the mouse pointer left has a certain class:

```
$('.smth').bind('mouseout', function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('certain_class')) {
      $('.fading_object_class').fadeOut("fast");
    }
});
```

Or if something else has a certain class:

```
$('.smth').bind('mouseout', function(){
    if($('#something_else').hasClass('certain_class')) {
      $('.fading_object_class').fadeOut("fast");
    }
});
```